# How do I use the @use module system of Sass?

Tags: sass, module, scss-mixins

Whenever I try to add a mixin or var from MediaQueries.scss it tells me it doesn't recognize them, they are in the same folder and I double checked vars and mixin names;

tast.scss:

```
$var: 200px;
@mixin blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

test.scss:

```
@use 'tast.scss';
.a {
    width: $var; // undefined variable
    width: tast.$var; // expected expression, was ".var;"
    @include blue; // no mixin named blue
    @include tast.blue; // expected "}", was ".blue;"
}
```

*It causes the same errors if I used this:

```
 @use 'tast';
```

Comment: Are you using Dart Sass? `@use`  is only supported in Dart Sass since `1.23.0`, no other implementations support it.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that... ummm is there any replacment method? for vscode extention.

Comment: What do you mean by replace method for VS Code extension? Are you compiling your Sass through an extension, or via the command line/build script?

Comment: Through the Watch Sass extention, and I mean a different compilation process, IE: diffrent extention or a compiler (external to vscode).

Comment: Got it. Let's see if I can help you out with this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the new `@use` syntax is only supported by Dart Sass, the Watch Sass extension for VS Code doesn't support it (and I don't know if it ever will) since it uses a version of SassJS - and quite an old one at that.

Instead, you should be able to install Sass directly on your machine with `npm install -g sass`. This will install the Dart flavour of Sass.

Once installed, and available on your PATH, you can then use a script to watch a Sass file or a whole directory and compile as you make changes.

```
"scripts": {
  // watch a single file
  "sass:watch": "sass --watch input.scss output.css",

  // watch a directory 
  "sass:watch": "sass --watch src/sass:build/styles"
}
```

Comment: Can that be used in vscode?
Can you please link any tutorial of this? I'm quite new to web development and package managing.
Thank you!

Comment: This would be set up as an npm script in your project. [This walkthrough](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/watch-and-compile-sass-in-five-quick-steps--cms-28275) should get set up with everything you need.

Since you need dart-sass, just change Step 3 to run `npm install sass` and then change Step 4 to use `sass` instead of `node-sass`

Comment: I really cannot thank you enough, I have been strugling with this issue for more than a month!

Comment: Glad it worked @AmitEshel. Don't forget to mark your question as answered ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sass doesn't need any filename extensions whenever you are importing a file or a module. Use `@use 'tast';` instead of `@use 'tast.scss';`.

Here is the [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use).

Comment: Even without extentsions it calls those errors, same ones, regardless of how I used @use. Any other idea?